# Subtracting Dates from Column in Sqlite

Tags: datetime, sqlite

I'm trying to figure out why none of the ways to subtract date isn't working on my query. I'm looking to compute the difference between the dates in days. I think my dates I'm working with is outside the bounds of value for sqlite time and date functions.

```
Table:
Name|date
"John"  "2019-04-07 12:09:20"   
"John"  "2013-08-01 11:10:37"
"James" "2013-11-11 04:12:14"   
"James" "2011-08-08 12:12:45"

I've tried: 

select name, datetime(max(date)) - datetime(min(date))
from table
group by name

and

select name, strftime('%d',max(date)) - strftime('%d', min(date))
from table
group by name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to take the difference of the Julian days between the two dates:

```
SELECT
    name,
    julianday(max(date)) - julianday(min(date)) AS num_days
FROM table
GROUP BY name;
```